# Elastic search aggregator price range from 0 to 0

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search aggregator query to get a list of available products based on the price range.

This is how my aggregator query looks like :

```
'aggs': {
            'prices': {
                'range': {
                    'field': 'price',
                    'ranges': [
                        {'from': 0, 'to': 0},
                        {'to': 4.99},
                        {'from': 5, 'to': 9.99},
                        {'from': 10}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to get the number of products that is free, so i have the ranges from 0 to 0. But that didn't work. The rest of the ranges are working fine. How can i get agg for price 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted from the [Range Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html)

> Note that this aggregation `includes` the `from` value and `excludes` the `to`
>   value for each range.

So, range aggregations `excludes` the `to` value you have entered. That is why, you didn't get any documents in bucket `0-0`.

Again, if you have given `from: 0, to: 1` this means the bucket of  0 ≤ value < 1 . And for `from: 0, to: 0` means bucket of 0 ≤ value < 0 , which doesn't includes `0`.

**Solution**:

Although, if you want to get the bucket of `0` values with the `range aggregation` then you can set the range `from: 0, to: 0.000000001`. Here `to` value is a minimum value greater than `0` (you can set as of your application).